# PHP Configuration for GMP and Large Number Arithmetic

Tags: php, configuration, xampp, gmp

I'm using PHP to do some of the problems on projecteuler.net, but I have found that with my current installation of PHP, I cannot compute numbers long or large enough to do some of the problems.

Some initial research on Stackoverflow and through Google has told me that I must install an extension to PHP in order to do math with very large numbers. One such extension that was suggested is GMP, but I am not entirely sure how to configure my PHP installation to use GMP.

I am currently running Windows 7 64-bit with an installation of XAMPP (I think the version is 2.5). Is there a way to configure my current PHP build to work with GMP? How?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try the [bc extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php). I believe that comes pre-installed on XAMPP. If that doesn't work, the requirements for GMP are [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gmp.requirements.php) and the instructions are [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gmp.installation.php).