# How can I properly call any math related function in a class/controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I tried to use the factorial php build in function `gmp_fact()` in one of my function in my class/controller.

I keep getting:

`Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\gmp_fact()`

Does anybody know why ? or How do I fix it ?

How's come I can use other functions like strlen, str_split, and so on ... ?

Do I need to include any kind of Math library or something ?

---

**My Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use View, Input, Redirect;

class CodeController extends Controller {

    public function getFactorial($num)
    {
        $fact = 1;
        for($i = 1; $i <= $num ;$i++)
            $fact = $fact * $i;
        return $fact;
    }

    public function codingPuzzle()
    {
        return View::make('codes.puzzle');
    }

    public function codingPuzzleProcess()
    {

        $word     = strtoupper(Input::get('word'));
        $length   = strlen($word);
        $max_value = ($length * 26);
        $characters = str_split($word);

        $num = 1 ;
        $index = 1;

        sort($characters);

        //dd($characters);

        foreach ( $characters as $character) {
            $num += gmp_fact($index) * $index;
            $index ++;


        }

        return Redirect::to('/coding-puzzle')
            ->with('word', $word )
            ->with('num', $num )
            ->with('success','Submit successfully!');

    }


}
```

Comment: Global functions are implicitly looked up. So this would indicate that your PHP setup doesn't have the GMP module enabled.

Comment: How do I enable it ? Should I enable it via `php.ini` or include it progarmmatically ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Configuration for GMP and Large Number Arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6670783)

Comment: Install GMP from http://php.net/manual/en/gmp.installation.php

Comment: It may just need to be enabled in `php.ini`.  Search for php_gmp.dll and make sure it's not commented out.  Uncomment it if you need to and restart your webserver.

Comment: I didn't see it when I try to search for it.